# SketchFlow Phone Screen instead of UserControl

Tags: windows-phone-7, sketchflow

Each time I create a new screen (by selecting "Create a connected screen") I get a xaml file which is of type UserControl rather than ChromePage. How can I add new Windows Phone pages? I dont want it to be a UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a SketchFlow Windows Phone application you are actually working with the desktop version of Silverlight. This is for ease of sharing/review for reviewers of the project. You are not actually creating a Windows Phone application, so the types are for the Desktop Silverlight version.

Comment: so how can I change the new screen into WindowsPhoneChrome page? Should I do this manually in XAML editor? Or should I always duplicate MainPage to get expected outcome?